# write value from input to firebase using typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and Typescript. I'm trying to figure out how to get a value from an input to firebase using AngularJS and Typescript. I've been following many tutorials but i cant seem to get this working unless i hard-code the values.

Here is my HTML;

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <!--Form Starts Here-->

      <div class="form-group col-xs-12"> 
        <div id="nameOfProp" class="form-group">
          <label for="nameOfProp">1. Name of Proposal:</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              id="nameOfPropInput"
              name="nameOfProp"
              placeholder="Name of Proposal"
              type="text"
              ngModel
              required
              #nameOfProp
            />
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12"> 
        <div id="tradingAs" class="form-group">
          <label for="tradingAs">Trading as:</label>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            id="tradingAsInput"
            name="tradingAs"
            placeholder="Trading as..."
            style="margin-bottom: 5px"
            type="text"
            ngModel
            required
          />
        </div>
      </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      type="submit"
      [disabled]="!f.valid "
      required
    >Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my component;

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {GplService} from '../../gpl.service';
import {OneData} from './onedata.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.css']
})
export class OneComponent /*implements OnInit*/ {
  // oneData: OneData[] = [
  //   new OneData('', 'Test One')
  // ];
  oneData: OneData[] = [
      new OneData('nameOfProp', 'tradingAs')
  ];
  constructor(private gplService: GplService) {}

 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   console.log(form);
    this.gplService.storeGpl(this.oneData)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
 }
```

Not sure if this is correct but i tried to create a data model as well;

```
export class OneData {
  public nameOfProp: string;
  public tradingAs: string;

  constructor(nameOfProp: string, tradingAs: string) {
    this.nameOfProp = nameOfProp;
    this.tradingAs = tradingAs;
  }
}
```

gpl service to connect to firebase and post;

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

```
@Injectable()
export class GplService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  storeGpl(oneData: any []) {
    return this.http.post('https://satibgpl.firebaseio.com/gpldata.json', oneData);

  }
}
```

Again, i need to know how to pass values from  in my html to the component instead of hardcoding it.
Thank you guys.

Comment: What is ```gplService``` and where's your Firebase code?

Comment: gpl service is the firebase post service to store data in the firebase database, main post updated

Comment: Ok. What is the error?

Comment: No error, i want to get input from my input fields in the HTML and write that data to firebase, instead, i get 'nameOfProp' and  'tradingAs' writing to the database instead of what i type in the input. 'nameOfProp' and 'tradingAs' is in the component, (if i change nameOfProp to anything else, that value will be written to firebase)